# Why NaN is displayed in IE8 when using datepicker and jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have a little issue with displaying a date received from C# code.

The part of code (on view side)

```
<div id="testdiv">
    <% string myDate = obj.MyDate.ToString( "yyyy/MM/dd" ); %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function () {
              var myJsDate= new Date("<%=myDate%>");
              $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
              $("#datepicker").datepicker('setDate', myJsDate);
          });
    </script>
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="my-date" />
</div>
```

Of course, **it works in IE9, Firefox and Chrome but on on IE8**.

As example, I provided a link to test yourself on IE8: http://jsbin.com/OyOCEqI/1/edit?html,js,output

There I put a date which I received from server side.

How to fix this in IE8 ?

Comment: Did you try a valid date -> `var dateTime = new Date(2013, 8, 10);`

Comment: Yes, but my script works very good in IE9 !

Comment: When setting the date with a string the browsers implements Date.parse differently and it's anyones guess what will work in older browsers. The above syntax, using integers instead, is the generally accepted cross-browser way to set a date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `"2013.09.10"` write `"2013/09/10"`

```
$(function(){
    var dateTime = new Date("2013/09/10");
    $("#tester").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
    $("#tester").datepicker('setDate', dateTime);
});
```

Comment: Yeah, but in IE9 works ! not in IE8...So that `/` doesn't matter

Comment: Worked with `.` or `/` ?

Comment: My question is why is not working with `.` on IE8 but works fine on IE9...Of course works with `/`

Comment: Because IE8's javascript engine doesn't understand . format and / is the standard format.